# How do I disable automatic mouse grab/ungrab in virt-manager?

Tags: virt-manager

Is there a way to manually control mouse/keyboard grabbing in virt-manager?
The current automatic system creates too many unnecessary mouse lockups. I'm looking for a way to change the settings but it seems to be nowhere in the GUI.

Comment: Why do you find virt-manager grabbing the mouse to be unnecessary?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I use GPU passthrough to simultaneously work on Windows under qemu. I find virt-manager failing to act properly with a second GPU. Constantly locking up the mouse each time the cursor reaches the edge

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Spice Server for display, then you can install Spice Guest Tools

1. Download the installer here https://www.spice-space.org/download.html
2. Run the .exe on your guest machine.

Immediately after installing (no reboot needed), virt-manager will no longer grab your mouse/keyboard.

Comment: This is madness!